# MVC4 REST Api page not found (404)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webapp2

After creating MVC4 project and creating a WebApi REST service, I am able to run it successfully.

The problem appears after I am installing from nuget the [Ext.Net.Mvc](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ext.NET.MVC) project.
The installation adds a new file and put this above the class decleration:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ext.NET.MVC

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ExtNetConfig), "Start")]
```

If I comment this, the project is WebApi is working, but Ext.Net is not working.

This is my App Start:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

it is not comming from the web.config since I have deleted all the Ext.Net changes and it still not working.

Thanks